# Keyword extraction using keyword database in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, keyword-search

I have a bunch of keywords stored in MySQL. For simplicity lets say the database has few keywords.

Lets say they are stored a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `keyword` (`keyword`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `keyword_ftx` (`keyword`)
)
```

and for now there are few keywords:

> 'C','C++','C#','Zend Framework', 'Visual Basic'

Now I want to extract these keywords from text. Such as:

> Here are some programming languages and frameworks such as C++, 
>   Visual Basic and Zend Optimizer does some stuff.

The obvious keywords which should be found from above text using the example keyword database entries should be:

> C++, Visual Basic

I tried 2 approaches so far.

**1- Put text into words and use an SQL query to search matching rows.**

> Ex: WHERE keyword IN ('word1','word2'...)
>
> This works quite fine for single words. However it can't find things
>   like 'Visual Basic' etc. which are 2 words.

**2- Use fulltext indexes and give text as natural language to mysql.**

> Ex: MATCH keyword AGAINST ('whole text')
>
> This works quite fine also, but it returns things like 'Zend
>   Framework' (since fulltext index takes Zend and Framework as separate
>   words, while it does not find C++ (on the account of word delimiters
>   in MySQL). I do not want to make my own collation for this purpose
>   only.

Most of the stackoverflow articles I found suggest method 1 or 2 but neither is working for me. Any ideas on what would be the best method to extract multi-word keywords while also matching other texts in database such as C++ etc. which has punctuation characters in a simple manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try approach one and use the full keyword?

Comment: If I have text as in the example I gave. How do you propose one would use full keyword?

Comment: You didn't provide an example of how you currently are actually querying. Is `'C','C++','C#','Zend Framework', 'Visual Basic'` on row or is each keyword its own row?

Comment: I already explained it in the question, in (1) I put the text into words. Then I use WHERE keyword IN ('word1','word2'...) I thought that was obvious. 'Visual Basic' is 2 words, so per my explanation I do not query like that because I can't tell where keyword starts in the text. I can not make a query string 'Visual Basic'
In (2) I do MATCH keyword AGAINST ('whole text'). Per my explanation.

I now added this information to the question too. I hope it would be more clear.

Comment: It's really hard to tell from your post what the schema of your database looks like, and a useful answer will likely depend on the structure of your data. Could you include the schema?

Comment: Lets say you can have freedom to assume whatever suits for best solution.But I have edited the question and added the create table statement for you. But I think this information wont help you to produce an answer.